# How do you say "we don't have any common interests"?

Tags: conversation

I was trying to say this to someone and it came out "我跟你们没兴趣", which I can tell isn't right.

To clarify, common interests here refer to personal interests or interests in activities, rather than shared goals in the context of business partnership or political alliances.

Comment: Literally it means 我们没有共同的兴趣.

Comment: look up "common interests" at e.g. jukuu: 共同的利益, find many(100) example sentences there, thus: 我们什么共同的利益也没有 or  都没有

Comment: 都也没有 is also possible

Comment: @user6065 according to the OP, "interests" should mean about hobbies, not profit. "我跟你们没兴趣" should mean "I am not interested in you guys".

Comment: Was this conversation in a business context or in a personal context?

Comment: Personal context.  Sorry I wasn't more clear

Comment: And what is the intention of this statement?  I think you need to handle it carefully because improper translation may lead to termination of friendship.

Answer (score 1):

"interest" has multiple related meanings and that's why Ghost's answer struggles. OP does provide some context but not enough.

Under the context of personal interest, common interest will be 共同的兴趣爱好 something we both like.

Under the context eg "The common interest between US and China" that will indeed be 共同的利益.

(In a constructed case, "my bank doesn't have common interests with his bank" this can even mean 一样的利息)

Comment: (although simply combining "common" with "interests" might yield ＂共同的爱好（兴趣？）＂）results for web search with ＂＇common interests＇是什么意思＂ seem to confirm jukuu's examples all translating it with 共同的利益, i.o.w. it seems＂common interests" has become a solidified expression only meaning 共同的利益，and 一样的利息 would have to be translated as "same interest rates"

Comment: The multi meaning comes from English, not translation. You might want to search "the meaning of common interest" in google. OP needs to resolve that in English first, then translate correspondingly.

Comment: It seems "common interest" must be distinguished from "common interests". See e. g. 100 example sentences in jukuu for "common interest",which mostly have things like 共同兴趣, besides a few with 共同的利益. But the overwhelming majority of example sentences 1 to 50 (there again is a total of 100, user gave up counting at 50) for "common interests" have 共同的利益，共同利益, or in 1 or 2 cases some variation of 利益. Admittedly ２ （１２，３８） have 共同的兴趣，one （２６）has 共有的兴趣或利益，and one （３６）has 共同关心。This seems to indicate that the usual meaning of "common interests" corresponds to ＂共同的利益＂。

Answer (score 0):

我们没有共同语言。这是地道的中文翻译方式，不是直译的。你也可以翻译成“我们没有共同的兴趣”。只是日常口语一般不会说的这么正式。

Comment: 共同语言 also includes common values, and is usually used for romantic relationships; it's not the most appropriate translation.

Comment: NO,not for romantica ralationships.I am a Chinese.

Answer (score 0):

**我们没有共同爱好.**

A local expression is : 我们玩不到一块儿去. (note that 儿, you should use 儿话音 to speak this sentence, or the feel will fail).

or a wild expression: 我跟你尿不到一个壶里. means you are two types, and cannot get along with each other. The opposite is 我跟他穿一条裤子. means you are very close. **Don't say** 我跟 **你** 穿一条裤子 to someone, that means a totally different thing, except you really mean that.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you saying this to someone's face? What is the context of this sentence?

In my experience people in China almost never say such things to each other, cus it's just not very polite. Cultural difference. Therefore any translations would probably come out wrong for a Chinese.

Answer (score 0):

I'd cut the sentence in 2, like this:

我们好像不能沟通。兴趣爱好完全不一样

沟通 is just the word you need in this kind of situation. it's about the ability to find a common ground (or not), between persons but also between cultures (西方人和中国人思想不一样！). Mostly translated as 'communicate', i'd rather put it as 'relate to'.

好像 ('it seems') softens up the message.

完全 underscores the difference